# Add buttons programmatically to Flow of ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-flow

I have seen the code for adding buttons to a ConstraintLayout in an existing question, but how do I do that with a Flow? That is, I do not want to define the top/left of the button relative to the ConstraintView itself, but I want the buttons to be next to the previous one and wrap at the end of the line.

I have tried the following but no button was showing.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val flow = findViewById<Flow>(R.id.flow);
    val lay = flow.parent as ConstraintLayout;
    val cs = ConstraintSet();
    cs.clone(lay);

    for (i in 1 .. 10)
    {
        val btn = Button(this)
        btn.text = "Test ${i}";
        btn.id = 49393+i;
        flow.addView(btn)
        cs.constrainWidth(btn.id, 400);
        cs.constrainHeight(btn.id, 100);
        cs.applyTo(lay);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/large_text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </ScrollView>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't ever added the button to the layout. The `Flow.addView` method only adds it to the helper if it's *already* a child of the relevant `ConstraintLayout`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#addView(android.view.View)):

> The referenced view need to be a child of the helper's parent.